# Run a page created in rails 4.1 Metodo Get y Post

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Run a page created in rails 4.1 from the tag  (html) code that acontinuacion I detail, for every time I Click on the menu I double the url:
pages / pages / pages (so in doubles in the url):

```
<li >
<a href="/pages">
<span>Paginas</span>
</a>
</li>
```

As execute a page in rails 4.1 from the tag  ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use link helper

`<%= link_to pages_path do %>
<span>Paginas</span>
<% end %>`